# Image with data uri src not loading in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, data-uri

I have a simple image populated from a data uri that loads fine in MobileSafari, but when I load the same webpage in a UIWebView, it shows as a broken image:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQSEhQUEhQUFBUUFBQUFBcVGBUUFhUVFRUWFhQUFBQYHSggGBolHBQUITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGhAQGiwkHx8sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw3NyssLC4rLP/AABEIAMEBBQMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAABBQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAIDBAUGBwj/xAA8EAABBAAEBAIJAwIFBAMAAAABAAIDEQQSITEFQVFhBnETIjJCgZGhsfAUwdFS4QdDkqLxI2JyghUzU//EABkBAAMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAwIEBf/EACURAAICAgEFAQACAwAAAAAAAAABAhEDEiEEEyIxQVEUYUJSgf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A8+GNjL2Bjgxxd7R2ZfMlU8bi7e7M8yAHKH/1Ac1mQtU7xosKIGhh+KujLTGAAL3AN3vZ8k1mLcHaEjNdgbarNw+bNTbPbddEOBnLE8ihKAR/BUpaR9jSZ2nh55DWAXQAsHuu0bNQHkuM4Y4R6Hkt93EbA8l4WRpNnXFcG/BMCpCQucgxJu7WgMTaj3Ua1NAy0mOnKpiRSB6w8iY6JjKVGxhJ9ZD0iLSd6WHJMdEuJlyt06qq2RXIMNYBcL3KuR4ZoF0LpKcZSkvw0mkZAZ65Wngt1z+NxHo5geWx8l0WAF6jovS6aV8fhjLGuS8iEEV2nMJJFMlkDRZ0ATbD2OQK5bifiRzLy0ADptqt7hONE8TJB7w17EGipwyqTpG5Y2lZbKBTkCqGAIJyCABSCKCAGlBOTUANQKcgmAxJFJAHy7hwpZEOGQuke2NgzPe5rGNG5c4hrQL6khXncHnLp2CJ5dh2udOK/wDqaw04u7aL0CJqeAMIHTucdmNPzdour4k9rQ1oGjTp2Vf/AA94E84Yz1TZHlrTyOVdBj/Cb3kEOHxXj9Q5SzP8R1Y0qMH01utaMFlXsN4Ye3cWtKDhhb7q5MsZP4VUkU8HhS5a8PDu6s4LChu4Vw4hrVy9mvY9iqzhpVlnDgq8nHI2+8FSm8TM93VGsV8Dlm23CNCLnAbBctLx57tgqz8ZI7nXkno/wZ1/6po3ICjfxBrro7Lk2sc7ckrSwWAI1Oi24uwSM7iVyPtmtaEBbPAseWDLICANj07IuwwYPVHdZ0+Io11WU54nsWdTWp10eLYdnN+dfdSNlb/UPmFyETuqMlVpuupdZJrlEHgX6dZPO1jS5xoDdclxfjfpHFosAan9h5rK4pjJIwbstd7PQHoSs2QERE5vWNuJPdPuvJXwaxKPJPi8QH+rXla6nwHIfRyMPuuBHxH9l5twfEPlk1Og6du69J8DsIEpPMtH3/lV10mkEn4M6hIpJLpOQBQKKRCYDUEUEABNKcU0oAaUE8hNQA2kE4IIA8ld4Kha4Phc+NzXBzSDdOaQ5p17gL0qLhsTJJXgNc7i1CTlkY3ClhrrchJ/9yuEi8QxnfRXGcWa7KRJ7Ps6+zrYrpqvOxdZ1OG+4mzsnghPmPB1vAcEyBuGwOjv00Hr1/mTZQ54HmSVb4jgxJII2/8ASllw8hYLPqPa9oD660Xb/wBK5XhcpdM05iTmLib1ujrfXVR+JpXuxDae5rqrMCbAogi/iurB1e6c5L6T/j+WtnVY/Dt9G6SB/qymP0JGuVrWnOR1sj6rJHpx74Pm1Y8eGlYxrRiHMa28ooECzdC+SYcXiWmhKHaXZbp91qfUY5P8NRwP47Nx2KxDQT6prtSHA+MunkexzQMg1I5lZcHE8QdCGOG3MK74Xw5aZnOABcb0U45YSlqnY3i1i2zI4vCDK4gKKKKl0UnBy9xde6li4IBuVl4ZtmFlSRixRK9hMIXEBbEXC2hXMPhBdAJPp2hLIrIY4WtFAbc0wu1s7K3xqIRxOINGt999AaXjmCxMv61rWGZxc4hxMhewhrznc9tUNBsK1+S3HpuG2/QPL+HquPnAb9lgYcZnHqdvJak0JcNT2AUWHjbEeS5JR3kVXihHCVqqweAaUPFPFEMJded+Wi/0bHPEY6vLQQPio8NxCLEND4XtcOo6jcEciqZcbjG64MwlbLskIcCCLB0/4XI+KOGTBoZH7GmYi7Ou3Yc12ENqwQ1wo6qMJOD2RT3wzieD4L9Oyy0ucaHqi9TsAvRPClCAaU4kl3zr7LkOMwGMEtuu262/COLtgH381WGa5qTCeNa8HXJFJJegcIECilSAGoJyCaAahScgUANTSnJqAAQgiUkAeOYvgBdM1serXOFg7gHf4Lqn+EI3xtyWxzTv1HPRZfC8Q709vpoBJ/gWuodxG2A6B11QPJR2qPkdWKFpg4RwaONwc15c5oPl02WVipg7FE6GrGqv4bijXPLAMo2c7p5K5J4ZjYC/MXE66lTflGomp3GfBQDg4iwDRQxjhlJIsjUJZMvKv5TmWaaTeY/RcEo+Vm1KkVsBiQ/Xry8l0HDmGiKAJ1HkqEuCj5N17aLRgxWzQMprmOndV6bAoTc2ZlJT4LrBoiFQw+JuwCbBrUUFSx/GHYeQB8dtd74P7L01NVZxyg4umb9q9gm0CVgw4rNRabBW7A7ZuoIF7fPdNOxeipxWEvNV6pFHp8VkYXhUURPo2taSfWdpZ+K4Dxb/AIgYkYmaIDIyN5a0CxbRdOJB1ur+KzOGf4gSl4sFzb1aTfyPJKfSyfNmo5Uvh67lAC5rxFhZJARES1xaa810uCeJImv2Dmh2u4sXSryQariljcWi6kpI8rxeCxQwscDGyRuD3ulokelLgRmc4H1m1pWvJbXgnwpLETJKSwuGrBzP9RH5uu6dgCdQR9U6GGjrquqWaU46USUUndjG4IgJn6YrV3FXSgEVc7UXgRpZGYmOgsEHohwSMMc0ctFqTtCoxAA2ORXFPHrNNF4z2jR1gUOMaSwhua/+2r37kI4aXM0HspV68JU1I4pRu0ZkbJbZo4ez7wIAs58+tkkVSm4i1xy5Mxo6hpoHbQmwR9VdQV31LclKlwRWGo1ZnObJT9H5r3sZaze5rvlQhheSMxkaBm97X27bZF3oVoOQWv5TriKF2F9bKOAbIC4yF2t9Mu/u62rrkbTSoZMm8rKwhqqAmlOKasGgJJWkgCk/w3hXG/RCz518lMzgkQ2a34i1OJU8SKVJlE2ilNwYHZkf2TJcE+qMdjsVpiRSNkWXjXw1vJHOzYFlU5kg+dKv+jYDYe4HuL+66qanNLTs4EfMUucjhlcRmB/6g9Cb90Mq3/EB/wBFOWC/pbF5J2SQho3IJ5lMfJksuObU0RyTjg3NLiGZgXyhrcvRpLTe+pCYOHZ2mi/SSMD1S22uy2aI5Eu+SajNeqKpRX3gy8RPLIWtY3Xd1fRaULM8QbM2yCdHb6bKxNwJ0TgYnn13Bp0203+ieOGTC81O7g/sqQUvqOfKovyshwQAc0AaXstTiOILGuJrblpXxVKDCPDgS07q9jI8wo7c1SLpkDwTxTC50rnC3AusAkmr5C+Sg4BwQSSgvoUR2/1FbXjPATRyuyktbm9XQOB5iyRdrI4fxOSN7XOYDWpLdDX/AInRd0ZXGyTR7FgZ6aG5mgAAV7R6eQ1BVmOW3b38AFyOF8UYfICZSORGV2a6B2A123TofE7JXARNkdZAvLQ/3Lhy236Kx4R2ol+Kd6QVvSzGSaa7qRgJ1OiWw9S26UfhVd09oBlnspSwDYrLY0UMVKQNVVw8uilx5HXX85qqDsByXn5n5HRBcHT8IlsUtJYfB5aPmtsFd+F3A58iphtK0ClaqTEUEkEwAgUUCUAAppTimFAAJSSJSQBXEiIkUGZHMucqWRIniRVA5ODkWBbEieJVRe40ctXWl7XytUTxJ1ZgA0EkAuvdo1GnU6DyTsrDFKXo3/Sp4lWJh+IEua00CXGxzDcthN4tiiAWghttB1u3WaptbVX1RY+w9tToBInCRc67iLjmFCugzAtp4b6xvnd6dE7/AOVkbuG04vDTRFZXhuZxvbX6LSkxfxWdEHKniNLUfDcWZGZjXtOFjQEA1dck3GymwiU+COjjKjF4xwwTtIO/JYDfDLR7TW/ALrXutVpD1WO416ZrU5iLwzG26aBe5PRaeD4cyM2K+StupMISc2/oUSF1qaMkqLDtBPkrRI7eaaBie2uaqzTck90m9aj85KrNr591jLKlwOCKk0lnX9vsqfpDen58EcVew+mydhMOavRee7bOpJJGtw2WnD6rrmNBAXJYOIg2V1WHPqhd3TNpHLmRJkCGQI2ha6diNCLEPRo2mlyezChGMJpjStC0Wx0IsTS1ElNtFsKAWJIWki2FGVmSzKLMjmUShMHJwcq9ohyLAs5kIWhoDRsNvzrqVCHJweixptFgOTmvVcOT2lAWyyHpSNzCrI8jR+aga5PD0wt+ybDsDQGjYfHfUnzQxDbTQ9WZG6IqxN/TJmYRsqj8QBvotGdqzMS0HdSlGjSdkb5272ovTjruo3xAeSUeGHe1hW2Nkgm6KeOyNdFJBE0bUeqlLSfJWUKMWMdfLT5fZQT338t/srLXC6O/7KZsI/NkpQ2GpUZEeBzakFo781eiwwHNX8o20RLfL7IjhSG8jZDEzULbboFgzPqj+fBbDX6LcKtoxL0TZkMyiL0sypVGaJCU0lMLk3MgCTMgXKO0rQIfaaXJhcgXJgOzIqO0EgMi0rTLSXPZYfadmUQKNosCYORDlAHI5kWFFgPTg9Vg5HMnYUWmyJwkUMTC7YK3DBXcoc6Go2GJhdsrTrAViGGlBiUK0tmZlJekUpXLPxFUQrc969FDLHpy3o+Y5LMsiYrRQLTVlTwa/n7qSPD3zA1qt/qnCA6d/oiMo2DkhOk5I9yRXclPewjoUwuy+758/iVVNSVmSdrL/p7X90cOwjQkHy5JkDwdtCOXPqrAjG/NbQhzmDmmSVWh+WiBfSoYrE77LGSaijUY2R4uXVbkT9B5BcnI+yK6j7rooHaBQ6aW0mVyxpBJ1JLSXWS08hXs0U30jzsTzN1R9kGtutqUvQzL1Fnr/FEdhhldrvdaCtNhqT13Sa55oWRvrXlW6eXJWjvr/VBYInuvUmjm5bUdFNmUZchmUpz2d0ZskLkMyjtK1gB9pKPMkgDIDki5VvSpCVcOx0FnMjmVb0iRlRsBZzJudVjKmGVGwFsvQEqomZOhBdsjYaR00EoDQAr2BjvU7Ln4GOaBra6eJwaz4LWLylb+CycLgf6XU9lSxL1A+chRibNsb3W5ZVTJuFIrzm1WlkJ0OoVp8Z17ftuFC/DnsNzqeg1tRlKLGpRBHNlFDSz+yMXnX3UXo6NaWa8tdk5kLu1dz3rfzWoyjH/onqWc187SDxf581BDrYPIHsNOpUjozrt899L0+Cr3YrgzwPe0HVuhH1TxJ0/PgoRE4dPntpeqnEda3yCXei/oWgOaT/O6q4uC2HsrsSdNHYKJ6VyxqdM5VjacPNdBh5NFk/o35r08r11BIsdwCrrCQBe5APwPVR6Rq2UzTTRezoZ1G9nIEbWdeR/5SDD2+fer8l1rLD9Oe0SZ9U8OVd7SN6+fek5jSRenzrzT7kauwtUS5ki9Rlhonoow5OMlL0OyfOlmUGdLOtAT5klDaCAOb9OOqImW5H4Tw45P/wBb/wCVbj8P4cf5f+538rmeAruc36RJ0q6scGg//MfX+VTxnheJ/sOdGf8AtOYfIpdgNznjIo3PWm/wjINp7H/gP5ULvC03KUfFv90dg0pooscrseKAUTvDuJb7zHDsCD9Ux/DcQP8ALcfKlz5MEr4OiGSNGngcVncG33+S6Nz/AFa7KpwjhDYYi55BdzPIdlLEcxVoQeOHJGclKXAhh826qT4Yi6JGlfArUy0mzMvZYcLC0YhdLRunDyFjunNxJ94ciNtzXNWJRSZ6W+V+an4x4aE8aforekN3zv4adk58rjew8hXO/wB0WQkn1AT17K5HwwjU6320V1rqmYceaKDTW1aij5FSiY9vltpRVqXC1sqU0dezuFKUufRvtpjziD25X8qpSMn8umg5dlSbKTuP2T8w3FhEZwfwXaRfbMB/G6ZPitDV7H6qkcRSiOJHNdEoqSNx6e3yMbK8kB1UHNJIHrHLtr1pPcXklx1s3/ZMEwHNWYpwjFjjD0bl06YhKdfID4Cv4RGJIAHTtrpqL7KyzKUHwA7j4qrgvwm+nK4xB27V9Sf3TmSmq5a/UUVHLhiNtfuocx5rNRSqiLx0XHYgnevp9EzOq+dHMnGo+jOpOHohygBTgVtSCiYOSUQSWrCjo0k0J1pCCkgigA0jlSCcCigG5UsqelaB2QywBwyna9ttUvRAE1z3U4TXxA/2WZKxp0REdU15/Apf0/c/RROiIWHA1sUZoTatYXBB2+w37qr+o9cjoPJTniTWbkWSCB2CxDGnLk05OjTa1jNgB10UL8QLs7LFl48A8NJFSWb6Ea1fkqPEsU+wQaaDbvIAlXcVXCJcmzjn3oNCfiFnStACrYHi4miEmazs4cw6tRSilx4Oi580Ui0JD2ij2P0VxlKlGCNeqtRHRRxr9NtlPiOGNWz5LDkkcuneVnYuEHX8pb31LY8tezHbMdirMOJIV2HhsUmp3+P7KceG2e6948nA/cLoULVmZdSkDDY1aUU4KzDwB7dpL8wL+YP7IR5mGnBPmPs1HJGa4NlRuYCoopFMHLQmVJsJzb8lWulpkqKaEO8+qlKJKUF8KWdOD0JYiO6ZazbRKiUOSVdxST3Edcimgogq5McCjabaVoAeCnWmAo2mA9Gky04FABSCARBQAbStIFEoAr4iO9/msPiWFJ94Gum/yXRFVcRgw7t5ISQcnm/iDAuOhcdDttYtVosc5jHQ5zmNVY0APTsux8Q+FnYhha2Ux3zAB/AuUxXg/GsDSx0MpYMoJzRktB0u7BPe1SK/sL/o3fDXDvQNaXn1nGxy18lrcegbJE17azZqHKyeS46HEY6N4diIJC1nshjWvF+bCdFscM4i/EEsMTw3R3rAtIPa+inkiaiwQ8QsAGxXI8uqtYfFCt1uR4cAafsnegUO2a3Ml0ml/wA0qE5OYaWD0XRvBHJQ20e5R8ku3yPYgw8IA2pWA2kc4UT5gFZcGVFssF2iqYht9004hN/Up+y0YUBjKUlpvpQUcyVFBzXJyjRzIEPIUMkAKkLkC9ZaBqyqYElO6RJZ1QtUbYRCKSqcgUkkkAFOCCSYDkgkkgBwRKKSAAikkgAlNRSQCAo5EkkmMgChd7f51RST+GfpKgUklhGwtUWI3RSTkNFWfZZkvNJJZKw9kblG1JJBZkrFI1FJaQh7USkkgQCgUkkmMickkkkB/9k=">
```

I have no idea why. Is there some magic configuration of the UIWebView that I've forgotten?

**Edit:**

In Safari Web Inspector pointing to the UIWebView, I notice that it is interpreting the data uri as `application/json`, whereas if I load the file from the same server in MobileSafari, web inspector correctly recognizes it as `image/jpeg`.

Comment: No magic configuration needed, everything should work. What `baseURL` are you passing when loading your HTML string? Try passing `[NSURL URLWithString:@"/"]` instead of `nil`.

Comment: I'm not injecting the html into the webview-- This is just in a webpage loaded from inside the app bundle via a loadRequest to NSURL of type file (NSBundle URLForResource:path). I also get the same problem if I host the file on a web server. However, see edit above re: mime-type.

Comment: We use `image/png` for our images (whatever their type actually is) and it works well.

Answer (score 3):

I copied your image src data uri and created a simple html file and loaded it in uiwebview.It was working fine and I did not see any problem in loading your jpeg image file using a local html file. Please see the html file created below.

```
<html>
<head><title>Sample</title></head>
<body>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
</body>
</html>
```

Loaded this sample.html in uiwebview in viewdidload using below code.

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];    
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmpSample.html"]];
NSData *data = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[data writeToURL:fileURL atomically:NO];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30 ];
[_yourUiWebviewView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Don't forget to add your html file to your xcode project.
Please check if this works for you.

Comment: Why do you write the file to a temp file before loading? I just use: `NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test.html" withExtension:nil]; [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]] ; `

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working around the issue by embedding the file in my app bundle, and setting the base URL of my webview to the parent of that file:

```
    [webView loadHTMLString:html 
             baseURL:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myimage" 
             withExtension:@"png"] URLByDeletingLastPathComponent ]];
```