# How to supply a base 64 image data string into a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, base64

I have a base64 image data in NSString. I want to straight display this in a UIWebView. How can I achieve this?

What I know so far is like this:

```
NSString * imageStr = /* some base64 image string */
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:imageStr options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

[webView loadData:imageData
         MIMEType:@"image/jpeg;base64"
textEncodingName:@"utf-8"
         baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

But it doesn't show anything on the UIWebView. What's the problem? Thanks.

My references so far:

- [Image with data uri src not loading in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172461/image-with-data-uri-src-not-loading-in-uiwebview)
- [Correct way to load image into UIWebView from NSData object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827891/correct-way-to-load-image-into-uiwebview-from-nsdata-object)

Answer (score 1):

Change your MIMEType to "image/jpg" its will work.

```
NSString * imageStr = /* some base64 image string */
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:imageStr options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

- [webView loadData:imageData
         MIMEType:@"image/jpeg;base64"
+ [webView loadData:imageData
         MIMEType:@"image/jpg"
textEncodingName:@"utf-8"
         baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

Comment: Sorry, it still not working. The webview just still display a black view.

Comment: maybe problem is your base 64 imageStr, not the way you display that as image in webview!!

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
NSString * imageStr = [self encodeToBase64String:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"]];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:imageStr options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

[_webview loadData:data
         MIMEType:@"image/jpg"
 textEncodingName:@"utf-8"
          baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

```
- (NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {
    return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}
```

Comment: It result in error: `ImageIO: read_user_chunk:1167: invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk` I have changed the `MIMEType` to `@"image/png"` but the issue still persist. Does this mean the image data is corrupt?

Comment: I think there is some issue with your added image. Try to remove that image from Xcode and add it back again.

Comment: The problem is the image base64 string is coming from a call to API, so I don't have the physical file to the image. But let me try to examine the image first.

Comment: @ChenLiYong, yea sure, check with that image string of base64.